# md5 with Android and PHP

Tags: php, android, md5, diacritics

I am using an md5 to secure my posts to a backendserver running PHP.
The parameters are send via HTTP Post.

I have one problem, the result of my md5 calculation is different on Android and the PHP server if there is a ü, ä or ö in one of the input parameters.

On Android, the hash is calculated via this function:

```
public static final String md5(final String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

on the PHP server I simply use

```
md5() function.
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue (ISO-8859-1 vs. UTF-8 for example). What character sets are you using? Can you show some code?

Comment: by the way, you might want to use SHA1 or another algorithm to secure your posts... MD% isn't secure anymore

Comment: Kindly check this [ link ]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494447/what-will-be-the-android-java-equivalent-of-md5-function-in-php)

Comment: @sivakg2000, the OP already do this.

Comment: @STT LCU it's unclear in this case how a hash secures anything anyway. Op said nothing about the attack scenario he was trying to defend against. In anycase SHA1 shouldn't be used in new developments unless backward compatibility issues are present, which doesn't seem to be the case at all. MD5 is almost never to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass **utf-8** encoded string to `md5` in PHP:

```
md5(utf8_encode($string));
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are using the platform's default charset.

Instead, try:

```
digest.update(s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I have replaces my digest.update() with yours, but I have still the same issue. Perhaps I have to set UTF-8 on PHP?